# How to convert a long format to wide format based on time differences

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following table:

```
library(data.table)

data <- data.table(Timestamp = c(as.POSIXct("2016-01-15 02:00:00"),
                             as.POSIXct("2016-01-15 04:00:00"),
                             as.POSIXct("2016-01-16 02:00:00"),
                             as.POSIXct("2016-01-15 05:00:00"),
                             as.POSIXct("2016-01-17 08:00:00"),
                             as.POSIXct("2016-01-17 08:00:00"),
                             as.POSIXct("2016-01-17 09:00:00"),
                             as.POSIXct("2016-01-22 09:00:00")),
               Activty = c("Eating Beef",
                           "Eating Cake",
                           "Eating Beef",
                           "Eating Cake",
                           "Sleeping",
                           "Eating Beef",
                           "Eating Beef",
                           "Sleeping"),
               Tag = c("S",
                       "S",
                       "E",
                       "E",
                       "S",
                       "S",
                       "E",
                       "E"
                       ))
```

What I want to do is retrieving the start and end times. If we view the table we get:

```
            Timestamp     Activty    Tag
1: 2016-01-15 02:00:00 Eating Beef   S
2: 2016-01-15 04:00:00 Eating Cake   S
3: 2016-01-16 02:00:00 Eating Beef   E
4: 2016-01-15 05:00:00 Eating Cake   E
5: 2016-01-17 08:00:00 Sleeping      S
6: 2016-01-17 08:00:00 Eating Beef   S
7: 2016-01-17 09:00:00 Eating Beef   E
8: 2016-01-22 09:00:00 Sleeping      E
```

So row 1, is the time when I start eating beef and row 3 is when I stop eating beef. So given a row with the same activity, the one with an S should be matched with the first E. The S indicates a starting activity, while the E an ending activity.

How should I approach this problem in data.table?

The final result should be something like this:

```
            StartTime  EndTime             Activty
1: 2016-01-15 02:00:00 2016-01-16 02:00:00 Eating Beef
2: 2016-01-15 04:00:00 2016-01-15 05:00:00 Eating Cake
5: 2016-01-17 08:00:00 2016-01-22 09:00:00 Sleeping
6: 2016-01-17 08:00:00 2016-01-17 09:00:00 Eating Beef
```

(This order is arbitrary, but is only used to depict the final result, i.e. combining the starting times with the ending times.)

Comment: Do you know the `sqldf` package?....it seems like a good candidate for this kinds of tasks!

Comment: Arg, I wish there was downvote button for comments...

Answer (score 0):

An approach using data.table :

```
library(data.table)
data<-data[,n:=c(1:.N), by=list(Activty,Tag)][order(Activty,Tag,Timestamp)]
x <-dcast.data.table(data, Activty+n~Tag, value.var = 'Timestamp')
x$n <- NULL

x

       Activty                   E                   S
1: Eating Beef 2016-01-16 02:00:00 2016-01-15 02:00:00
2: Eating Beef 2016-01-17 09:00:00 2016-01-17 08:00:00
3: Eating Cake 2016-01-15 05:00:00 2016-01-15 04:00:00
4:    Sleeping 2016-01-22 09:00:00 2016-01-17 08:00:00
```

It is close to the desired output.